# Unit testing in VS2012 Update 2 with ReSharper 7.1.3 and TFS Express

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, tfs, resharper

After updating VS2012 to Update 2 and seeing my unit tests stuck in pending mode when running them with ReSharper, I downloaded version 7.1.3 as recommended and could once again run my tests. A few weeks after that, I downloaded TFS Express just to play around with it and see how it worked. Today, after deciding it's not beneficial for me to keep it on my local machine anymore, I uninstalled it. Suddenly, until tests would no longer run. I re-installed it, and as if by magic, my unit tests ran again.

Does anyone know what TFS and VS2012 have in common regarding unit testing? What could've happened during un-installation that was fixed with a re-install? And even more importantly, what did TFS Express change in VS2012's handling of unit testing? Any insight would be much appreciated as I couldn't find much detail on the web...